# Convert 12-bit number into 2 8-bit bytes

Tags: c, binary, bit-shift, integer-arithmetic

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to convert a (maximum) 12-bit number into 2 8-bit bytes (where one of the values will obviously not be able to exceed 4-bits).

For example, I can convert `7` (the 4-bit value) and `60` (8 bit value) integers into `3079` via:
`7 + (60 << 8) & 0xfff;`

But I cannot reverse this process, extracting `60` and `7` FROM `3079`.

I use the following for 16 bits, but I cannot figure out how to modify it for 12-bit values as they do not result in the original value:

```
(calcMSB << 8) | (calcLSB & 0xff)
```

Comment: The `60` value isn't right because, as you say, it can't exceed 4 bits (which that value does). Your last statement should work for any bit width between 9 and 16.

Comment: Apologies, the `7` falls into the 4 bit category. Was a late night!

Comment: But why `60 & 0x0F`, then?

Comment: This is the excerpt from existing source code, which I am trying to understand myself - its part of a large lookup table to retrieve the relevant strings. The msb should be the 8 bit value and the lsb should be the 4 bit value. This: `7 + (60 << 8) & 0xfff;` is how they calculate the 12-bit value.

Comment: But that's not right either. If, as you say, the 7 should be in the 4-bit category, then the 8-bit part should be shifted 4 bits to the left to make room, not 8. So pack: `packed = (fourbitpart + (eightbitpart << 4)) & 0xfff`, and unpack: `fourbitpart = packed & 0xF; eightbitpart = packed >> 4;`.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly there is no difference between 16 bits and 12 bits here.
See pseudocode below:

```
calcLSB = value12bit & 0xFF; // get LSB byte
calcMSB = value12bit >> 8;    // shift bytes over LSB and take them
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't correct. It equates to `calcLSB = 255, calcMSB = 12`

Comment: Updated (mistaken operator, was `&&`, should be `&`).